# read write binary into a string c

Tags: c, string, pointers, binaryfiles

So, I looked around the internet and a couple questions here and I couldn't find anything that could fix my problem here. I have an assignment for C programming, to write a program that allows user to enter words into a string, add more words, put all words in the string to a text file, delete all words in string, and when they exit it saves the words in a binary, which is loaded upon starting up the program again. I've gotten everything to work except where the binary is concerned.

I made two functions, one that loads the bin file when the program starts, one that saves the bin file when it ends. I don't know in which, or if in both, the problem starts. But basically I know it's not working right because I get garbage in my text file if I save it in a text file after the program loads the bin file into the string. I know for sure that the text file saver is working properly.

Thank you to anyone who takes the time to help me out, it's been an all-day process! lol

Here are the two snippets of my functions, everything else in my code seems to work so I don't want to blot up this post with the entire program, but if need be I'll put it up to solve this.

SIZE is a constant of 10000 to meet program specs of a 1000 words. But I couldn't get this to run even asking for only 10 elements or 1, just to clear that up

```
void loadBin(FILE *myBin, char *stringAll) {
    myBin = fopen("myBin.bin", "rb");
if (myBin == NULL) {
    saveBin(&myBin, stringAll);
}//if no bin file exists yet

fread(stringAll, sizeof(char), SIZE + 1, myBin);

fclose(myBin); }
```

/

```
void saveBin(FILE *myBin, char *stringAll) {
int stringLength = 0;
myBin = fopen("myBin.bin", "wb");

if (myBin == NULL) {
    printf("Problem writing file!\n");
    exit(-1);

stringLength = strlen(stringAll);
fwrite(&stringAll, sizeof(char), (stringLength + 1), myBin);
fclose(myBin); }
```

Comment: `fwrite(&stringAll` should be `fwrite(stringAll`?

Comment: `saveBin(myBin, stringAll)`, not `&myBin` which would be a `**FILE`

Answer (score 0):

You are leaving bad values in your myBin FILE*, and passing the & (address) of a pointer.

Pass the filename, and you can (re) use the functions for other purposes, other files, et al.

```
char* filename = "myBin.bin";
```

Pass the filename, buffer pointer, and max size to read. You should consider using stat/fstat to discover file size

```
size_t loadBin(char *fn, char *stringAll, size_t size)
{
    //since you never use myBin, keep this FILE* local
    FILE* myBin=NULL;
    if( NULL == (myBin = fopen(fn, "rb")) ) {
        //create missing file
        saveBin(fn, stringAll, 0);
    }//if no bin file exists yet
    size_t howmany = fread(stringAll, sizeof(char), size, myBin);
    if( howmany < size ) printf("read fewer\n");
    if(myBin) fclose(myBin);
    return howmany;
}
```

Pass the file name, buffer pointer, and size to save

```
size_t saveBin(char *fn, char *stringAll, size_t size)
{
    int stringLength = 0;
    //again, why carry around FILE* pointer only used locally?
    FILE* myBin=NULL;
    if( NULL == (myBin = fopen("myBin.bin", "wb")) ) {
        printf("Problem writing file!\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    //binary data may have embedded '\0' bytes, cannot use strlen,
    //stringLength = strlen(stringAll);
    size_t howmany = fwrite(stringAll, sizeof(char), size, myBin);
    if( howmany < size ) printf("short write\n");
    if(myBin) fclose(myBin);
    return howmany;
}
```

Call these; you are not guaranteed to write & read the same sizes...

```
size_t buffer_size = SIZE;
char buffer[SIZE]; //fill this with interesting bytes
saveBin(filename, buffer, buffer_size);
size_t readcount = loadBin(filename, buffer, buffer_size);
```

Comment: The two small tweaks suggested to my code and a couple syntax errors I fixed afterwards got it working, definitely not the prettiest code but it's summer classes time to move on XD. EDIT: didn't mean to post that, wanted to say THANK YOU for your in depth post on my code. I tried to use it, was looking up what a buffer was/does and fstat and the other pieces of code I didn't understand there, but I got completely lost. If you got a good reference for me to understand some of that better I'd gladly look into it, I'm just appreciative of getting exposed to a couple more concepts I'm sure to see!